# Why does glBindTexture() give me the error GL_INVALID_ENUM although GL_TEXTURE2D is valid?

Tags: java, opengl-es-2.0

The [documentation](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/) of OpenGL's `glBindTexture()` function says

> [...] Must be either
>                       GL_TEXTURE_2D or
>                       GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP.

Even though I call the function like this:

```
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
```

it gives me the *GL_INVALID_ENUM* error.

I already tried calling the `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` function but it didn't succeed.

What causes this?

Comment: Are you completely sure that the error is from this call? When you call `glGetError()` before making this call, it returns `GL_NO_ERROR`? And only after this call it returns `GL_INVALID_ENUM`? Sorry about the obvious question, but it happens surprisingly often that people call `glGetError()` and assume that the returned error was triggered by the immediately preceding call, while the error status was in fact set by an earlier call.

Comment: @Reto Koradi Thank you for your answer. I will check that.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Your presumption was right. The error is actually generated before this statement. But I have no idea where it comes from.

Comment: Spread `glGetError()` calls around your code, and see where the first error is detected. You can use kind of like a manual binary search. One you found a place in the code where there's no error, and a later one where there is an error, you place another `glGetError()` about halfway between them, and gradually reduce the range this way until you narrowed it down to a single call.